# Unable to align button icon in the center on the Ext JS button

Tags: css, button, extjs, alignment

I want to display only an icon on the **Ext JS 4.1.1 button** (no text). I want the width of button be be a little longer than the icon width. When displayed, the icon is always left aligned. I want it to be centered in the button.

I am unable to achieve the above using either the `alignTo` method or the `background-position` in CSS.

The icon is 32x32px png file.

**Ext JS code:**

```
var topToolBar = Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
                width: '100%',
                items: [{
                    iconCls: 'home32',
                    width: 60,
                    iconAlign: 'center',
                    scale: 'large'
                }]});


            var master = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                layout: 'anchor',
                anchor: '100% 100%',
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                tbar: [topToolBar]
            });
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.home32 
{
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url( images/32/home.png ) !important;
}
```

Comment: Have just posted the code also.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget after all Ext Js  is plain css-html.  Try the old time classic way.

Button definition

```
 xtype:'button',
                    iconCls:'contactIcon80',
                    iconAlign:'top',
                    width:120,
                    height:100,
                    html:'<span class="bigBtn">Damn you hayate/span>'
```

Button Icon Class

```
.contactIcon80 {
background-image: url(../images/calendar80.png) !important;
width:80px!important;
height:80px!important;
margin-right: auto !important;
margin-left: auto !important;
```

}

Html span class (this is for placing the Text if you have in the correct position )
And with this way you can use bigger button icon size  not just only 16x16 - 24x24 - 32x32

```
.bigBtn {
position: absolute;
bottom: 4px  !important;
```

}